# Why are p orbitals most important for stability?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals, stability, periodic-table

Is there nice way to see/show/derive why p orbitals are so important for stability? Or asked differently: Why are elements with filled p orbitals on the right side of the periodic table? Why aren't elements with fully filled s or d shell like Beryllium or Zinc noble?

Comment: What should I change about my question? It has been closed for being "to broad", but my question is what it is and I assume many people have the same question. Where else should I ask it?

Answer (score 3):

This question is legitimate, I do not know if this will be give a complete answer, but here is the basic principle.

We have to define first the orbital at the outermost shell.
When you have to solve the hydrogen atom, there is a term $+\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}$ from the angular momentum $L^2$ which gives a positive energy when angular quantum number $l>0$. This means that the $s$-orbitals ($l=0$),  are closer to the nucleus as compared to the other orbitals which have a kind of "centrifugal force" and are farther from the nucleus, $s$-orbital cannot form the outermost shell (farther away from the nucleus).

Now in the case of $d$-orbitals ($l=2$), $f$-orbitals ($l=3$) and $g$-orbitals ($l=4$) :
They are farther away from the nucleus compared to the $p$-orbitals, **however** their radial extent is not larger than the $p$-orbitals because their filling starts from $n \ge 3$  whereas the $p$-orbitals and $s$-orbitals already have a large spatial extent (more number of nodes). Therefore, $d,f,g$ orbitals are more localised as compared to $s,p$ orbitals.

To conclude, a $p$-orbital is always the most delocalized orbital because of its orbital angular momentum and its spatial extent, so it defines the outermost shell.

This outermost shell $p$-like defines the stability when it is filled because another added electron will be so far from the nucleus that the compound will be very unstable (low electron affinity $A$). $p$-orbitals are filled when the potential of the nucleus is larger as compared to the innermost orbitals, $p$ block elements are often more electronegative (ionisation potential $I$ is high). When $p$-orbitals are filled, the compound is very stable $I-A>>$ : Noble gases. The filled $s,d,f$-orbitals have lower $I-A$ values than that of noble gases.